# Develop Network Mapping/Pinging Application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, network-programming, mapping, ping

I am interested in creating an application that will be used to monitor non-local connections.  The application will simply show a map and have markers that indicate all of the locations.  There will be a green arrow if the ping was successful and red arrow if the ping was unsuccessful.  I know this question is broad, but I'm not sure what the best language to use to develop this.  The end goal is to display this application on a TV/Monitor as a way to monitor the network visually.  The question is what is the best language to use?  Also, use Google maps API? It would look something like this..
[image: Green = Up, Red = down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.spiceworks.com/free-network-mapping-software/

This is a fantastic free software that maps your network connections. It is written in Ruby-on-Rails.

http://larsgebhardt.de/using-google-maps-api-with-ruby-on-rails/

This site gives a little bit of tutorial on how to use RoR with the Google Map API